# Using a variable in an object reference javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute a javascript call to my array. 
Howerver I am having a few problems. The following three statements work perfectly fine.

```
 var Greetings = Hi;
 console.log (Greetings);
 console.log (obj.Hi);
```

I want to execute this statement but the console log says my variable is undefined.

```
 var search = obj.Greetings;
 console.log (search);
```

How can I execute the last two lines of code so I am returned with what is returned during (obj.Hi)

Comment: `new` is a protected keyword in Javascript - you can't name a variable `new`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_keywords_as_of_ECMAScript_2015

Comment: Guessing you did not see the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token new" unless the above is not what you are really running.

Comment: New is not the reason why this didnt work. Please re analyze